# Nullreference in microsoft.speech when getting installed recognizers even though there are

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition

I'm trying to add speech recognition to my Unity project. The turtle demo works fine; I can control it with my voice.

In my own project I'm trying to search for the english language recognizer:

```
string recognizerId = "SR_MS_en-US_Kinect_11.0";
RecognizerInfo ri = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers ().Where (r => r.Id == recognizerId).FirstOrDefault ();
```

Which results in a nullreference error.

I've also tried searching through all installed recognizers:

```
foreach (RecognizerInfo recognizerinfo in SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers()) 
    {
        string value;
        recognizerinfo.AdditionalInfo.TryGetValue("Kinect", out value);
        if("True".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && "en-US".Equals(recognizerinfo.Culture.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return recognizerinfo;
        }
    }
```

Same error. I have checked my registry and it looks fine to me: http://puu.sh/gOOyy/9a900bc335.png

Here's the full error i'm getting:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.HKEYfromRegKey (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey)
Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.RootHKEYFromRegPath (System.String rootPath)
Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.RegistryDataKey.Open (System.String registryPath, Boolean fCreateIfNotExist)
Microsoft.Speech.Internal.ObjectTokens.ObjectTokenCategory.Create (System.String sCategoryId)
Microsoft.Speech.Recognition.SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers ()
SpeechRecognition.GetKinectRecognizer () (at Assets/SpeechRecognition.cs:15)
SpeechRecognition.CreateSpeechRecognizer () (at Assets/SpeechRecognition.cs:31)
SpeechRecognition.InitializeKinect () (at Assets/SpeechRecognition.cs:76)
SpeechRecognition.Start () (at Assets/SpeechRecognition.cs:83)
```

I have the Microsoft Serve Speech Platform Runtime, Microsot Speech platform SDK v11.0 and Kinect for Windows Speech Recognition Language Pack (en-US) installed and I have tried reinstalling to no avail, unfortunately. Hopefully someone can help me.

edit: even if I just test this:

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<RecognizerInfo> test = SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers();
```

I get the same error. If there were no installed recognizers, the test variable would just be null right?

edit2: I just tested this code in Visual Studio and it works. So for some reason Unity doesn't want to access the registry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Given that the NRE is coming from an internal SDK function, I don't see how this link could be helpful. Rather, information regarding how the SDK works should be given, or perhaps it is a bug in the SDK.